# Microphone permission for an individual tab/webpage in Safari on Mac

Tags: safari, permission, privacy, microphone, web-app

So on my MacBook, I gave microphone access permission to a tab in Safari. Afterwards, I tried to revoke the permission, but could not find where the setting was.

In System Preferences - Privacy and Security - microphone, Safari is not on the list. In Safari settings, there is no microphone permission setting.

(Also have to mention that the tab was an incognito tab)

I have a few questions:

1. If it was a normal tab (not in Private/incognito mode), and the tab asked for microphone permission, and the user gave it (looked as if given to the domain, from how the prompt message was phrased). Would any tab of the same domain automatically have microphone permission in the future, without asking the user?
2. If a normal (not in Private/incognito mode) tab was given permission in Safari, would Safari normally be listed under System Preferences - Privacy and Security - microphone?
3. If it was a private/incognito tab, given microphone permission, would it be like a one-off thing that expired once the tab was closed?

Comment: Safari's mic [& many other] permissions are in Safari prefs > websites. idk about incognito browsing.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin thank you it worked!